# Xpath builder in Python

Tags: python, xml, xpath, selenium

I'm building relatively complicated xpath expressions in Python, in order to pass them to selenium. However, its pretty easy to make a mistake, so I'm looking for a library that allows me to build the expressions without messing about with strings. For example, instead of writing

```
locator='//ul[@class="comment-contents"][contains(., "West")]/li[contains(., "reply")]
```

I could write something like:

```
import xpathbuilder as xpb
locator = xpb.root("ul")
             .filter(attr="class",value="comment-contents")
             .filter(xpb.contains(".", "West")
             .subclause("li")
             .filter(xpb.contains (".", "reply"))
```

which is maybe not as readable, but is less error-prone. Does anything like this exist?

Answer (score 1):

though this is not exactly what you want.. you can use css selector

```
...
import lxml.cssselect
csssel = 'div[class="main"]'
selobj = lxml.cssselect.CSSSelector(csssel)
elements = selobj(documenttree)
```

generated XPath expression is in `selobj.path`

```
>>> selobj.path
u"descendant-or-self::div[@class = 'main']"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lxml.etree](http://codespeak.net/lxml/tutorial.html#the-e-factory) that allows to write code as the following:

```
from lxml.builder import ElementMaker # lxml only !

E = ElementMaker(namespace="http://my.de/fault/namespace", nsmap={'p' : "http://my.de/fault/namespace"})

DOC = E.doc
TITLE = E.title
SECTION = E.section
PAR = E.par

my_doc = DOC(
  TITLE("The dog and the hog"),
  SECTION(
    TITLE("The dog"),
    PAR("Once upon a time, ..."),
    PAR("And then …")
  ),
  SECTION(
    TITLE("The hog"),
    PAR("Sooner or later …")
  )
)
```

Comment: The lxml API is wonderful. Also really fast, because it is mostly simple bindings to the libxml2 C library.

Comment: I'm trying to build xpath statements. This seems to build XML statements.